# Paypal Sandbox not Showing Transactions

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We have had a website developed on Sitecore 8.1 for our business, which incorporates Paypal payments.  We have a Paypal sandbox set up and are successfully making payments to it and creating orders on the website.  The problem is that we cannot see ANY transactions in the seller sandbox OR the buyer sandbox.  There are also no transactions showing in the developer site login.

I created a new sandbox, changed the name and updated the website to reflect the REST API id/secret and the new name shows on the check out page, so we are definitely making payments to the correct sandbox (and they are returning a success code).

I need to be able to see successful transactions to convince the business that the payments are actually being taken before we switch over to live, how can I do this?